# SQL how create a Boolean column based on the value of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean

I have an sql query that retrieves a column which values are strings. I want to create a column next to it that takes a value of 1 if the substring 'MB' is contained in the value or 0 otherwise

Comment: Could you provide your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output another column with a calculated value like this:

```
select COLUMN, IF(LOCATE('MB', COLUMN) > 0, 1, 0) as STR_FOUND
  from TABLE
```

See the documentation of [`locate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`if`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) for further Information.

Comment: I don't see a LOCATE function in MSSQL

Comment: This is not MSSQL. It is MySql

Answer (score 3):

You can try it using the case when then like this:

```
select case when INSTR('mycol', 'MB') > 0 then 1 
       else 0 
       end as myBoolCol
```

Comment: How would one know `pos` and `len`?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann:- Updated the answer. However I am not sure how OP is extracting the `'MB'` string.

Comment: Thanks a ton! You've helped a lost soul. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
select column, 
       case when column like '%mb%' then 1
       else 0 end 
from table
```

This works for both MSSQL and MYSQL